# Prove that the function has at least one stationary point in the set $(-1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, stationary-point

> Given a function $f:[-1,1]{\rightarrow\mathbb{R}}$ such that $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ and differentiable on $(-1,1)$ and such that$$f(-1)=0, \space f(0)=-1, \space f(1)=2.$$
>   Prove that the function has at least one stationary point in the set $(-1,1)$

The function is continuous in a closed bounded interval, then
we can apply Weierstrass Theorem which implies that the function has the
maximum and the minimum in the domain $[−1, 1].$

Not too sure where to go from here.

Comment: It's not "Weierstrasse" you need but the "mean value theorem".  There must exist a point, between x= -1 and x= 0 where the derivative is (f(0)- f(-1))/(0-(-1))= (-1- 0)/1= -1.  There must exist a point between x= 0 and x= 1 where the derivative s (f(1)- f(0))/(1- 0)= (2- (-1))/1= 3.  Now, a derivative is not necessarily continuous, it does satisfy the "intermediate value property. Since the derivative is negative at one point and positive at another, there must be a point between where the derivative is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about it is that you can use the mean value theorem on $[-1,0]$ to see that the derivative is negative somewhere in $(-1,0)$. You can then apply the mean value theorem again on $[0,1]$ to see that the derivative is positive somewhere in $(0,1)$. Since derivatives satisfy the intermediate value property (this is called Darboux's theorem) it follows that the derivative must have a zero somewhere in $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $f$ continuous it has Darboux property, therefore $f(0)=-1, \space f(1)=2$ implies there is $x_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$. Now apply Rolle theorem to $f$ restricted to $[-1, x_0]$

Answer (score 0):

You can actually prove more about this stationary point:  it must be a local (and absolute) minimum.  By compactness, the function has an absolute minimum. By the endpoint knowledge and that $f(0)$ is smaller than both, this min cannot be at the ends.  Hence the min must be a local min, so $f'(c)=0$ at this point.

Comment: To clarify, I do not mean to imply that the stationary point is unique.  Other people's arguments in this thread produce a stationary point that may not be a local min (I suppose).  I only meant that in my argument you get the bonus fact that it is a local min.