# Proving the existence of a stationary point on $(0,2)$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Given a function $f:[0, 2]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous on $[0,2]$ and differentiable on $(0, 2)$ such that $f(1)=0$ while $f(0)f(2)>0$, show that there exists at least one stationary point in the set $(0,2)$

Right away we have $f(0)>0$ and $f(2)>0$ and intuitively it seems like we could find $f(a)=f(b)$ and use Rolle’s Theorem. I’m just not sure how to put this into words and construct the proof rigourously. I struggled to apply the steps used in similar questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2393453/995613) because less is known about the exact values of the function in this case - only that it’s positive at certain points.

I checked with the mean value theorem directly but it doesn’t seem to lead to anything.

$$f’(c)=\frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2-0}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis implies that both $f(0)$ and $f(2)$ must be of the same sign.

Suppose $f(0)$ and $f(2)$ are both positive. As $f(1)=0$, the minimum of $f$ on $[0,2]$ must be attained at a point $\alpha$ which is different from $0$ and $2$. $\alpha$ would be a critical point then.

If both $f(0)$ and $f(2)$ are negative, then as $f(1)=0$, the maximum of $f$ must be attained at a point different from that of $0$ and $2$. That would be the critical point.

Comment: thank you! forgot they could both be negative also

Comment: Yeah...........!